# What is a word for a place to study and rest?

Tags: single-word-requests

My father wants to name our house as a place to study and rest. Is there any single short word which means this. Any suggestion are welcome.

Comment: If you don't mind the religious inflection, consider naming your house **The Sabbath**, which pays attention to both the *place* and *time* of rest.

Comment: What does "name our house" mean here?  Describe your house?  Or actually christen it?

Comment: In the Christian tradition a religious "retreat" is an opportunity to withdraw temporarily from the stresses of everyday life and concentrate on prayer, contemplation and the study of the scriptures an other religious texts. Retreats often take place in a monastery or convent but can also take place in dedicated "retreat houses". You could, therefore, call your house "The Retreat".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an overly broad request for name suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

**[den](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/den)**

> A secluded room for study or relaxation.

---

You can consider **[snuggery](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/snuggery)** also

> a cosy and comfortable place or room

Answer (score 1):

The satisfying word you are looking for is [**phrontistery**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/phrontistery).

> a place for thinking or study

-Merriam Webster

Answer (score 0):

Ranch - a one story house with a low pitch roof : http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ranch%20house

Cabin - a small house of simple design : http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cabin?s=t

Cottage - a small one-story house : http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cottage

Chalet - a herdsman's hut in the Swiss Alps, or a ski or vacation facility of similar design :  http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/chalet?s=t

Answer (score 0):

Consider "[**retreat**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/retreat)" and "[**nest**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nest)."

> **nest**: a snug retreat or refuge; resting place; home.
>
> **retreat**: a place of refuge, seclusion, or privacy.

Answer (score 0):

**[Studio](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/studio)** captures part of your requirements. The house could be called The Studio.

**[Muse](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/muse)** "to think about something carefully or thoroughly" again, only captures part. The house could be called The Muse.

**[Retreat](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/retreat)** as in a place to go to get away from it all to think and relax.

Answer (score 0):

try these:

sanctum- A private place from which most people are excluded

atelier - A workshop or studio, especially one used by an artist or designer.

retreat- a period or place of seclusion for the purposes of prayer and meditation

haven - A place of safety or refuge

all definitions are from oxford dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions on the serious side:

- **The Study**
- **The Library**

I have fell asleep in more than one study and library.  Actually I might have slept more than been awake in each.

On the lighter side I suggest:

- **The Couch**
- **The Coffee House**

You certainly study and rest a lot on a couch and in a coffee house.

And my favorite is a bit poetic and more than one word:

- **Under the Willow Tree**

When I picture someone under a willow tree they are either napping or reading a book or both.

Answer (score 0):

**Meditation**

> from Old French *meditacion* "thought, reflection, **study**", and directly from Latin *meditationem* (nominative, *meditatio*),  "a thinking over, meditation," from *meditatus*, pp. of meditari "**to meditate, to think over, consider**," frequentative form from PIE
>   base *med- "to measure, limit, consider, advise" (cognates: Greek *medesthai*
>   "think about," *medon* "ruler," Latin *modus* "measure, manner," [...] mederi "**to heal**," medicus 
>   "**physician**," ...)

The verb **meditate** which [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/meditate) define as:

1. Focus one’s mind for a period of time, in silence or with the aid of chanting, for religious or spiritual purposes or as a method of **relaxation**
   1.1. (meditate on/upon) Think deeply about (something):
   *he went off to meditate on the new idea*

Thus to name a home  *Meditation* suggests a place which provides the space and necessary  conditions to think things over in a calm reflective manner (i.e. to study something in depth) and at the same time, achieve a state of deep relaxation and inner calmness. In other words, a place where to rest one's body and mind.